# Problem with the background image on a header

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am following a tutorial and unable to proceed further --
location of 
background image file is >>Project/resources/css/img/hero.jpg and
 style.css is                     >>Project/resources/css/style.css

But I cannot place this image on the header, below is the code -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEVqx.jpg

```
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(img/hero.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
```

I have also tried these options but none is working (with single/double and without quotes) -

```
url(/img/hero.jpg)
url(resources/css/img/hero.jpg)
url(/resources/css/img/hero.jpg)
```

Comment: `#000000b2` is not a valid HEX color. HEX color are 3 or 6 digits long not 8.

Comment: Hey, thanks. It was a typing mistake here!! Corrected it now.

Comment: Please add your relevant html to the question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mtIchu3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may helpful for you:

```
body {
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("/resources/css/img/hero.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    }
```

If the above code not working you can try:

```
body {
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("css/img/hero.jpg and");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man. First one pretty much does the job but I wanted it to be in the header. When I'm trying to create features <section> below the image, it automatically puts that text on the image not under the image.

Comment: It was a silly mistake I started the header code adding ".header". Just had to remove full-stop. LoL

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 background: url("img/hero.jpg")
```

or

```
background-image: url("img/hero.jpg");
```